# Return the total rows affected by SQL Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code in sql:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
Begin Transaction
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES(/*Some Values*/)
INSERT INTO TABLE_B VALUES(/*Some Values*/)
INSERT INTO TABLE_C VALUES(/*Some Values*/)

Update Table Set Values A = A WHERE id = @id /* Some thing like that*/
Commit Transaction
```

So, i just wanted to know the total number of rows affected by in my Transaction Block of Insert and Updte statement

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`@@ROWCOUNT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) variable

To get  Inserts + all affected rows of update , declare a variable and store rowcount values in it.

```
DECLARE @totalRows INT
SET @totalRows = 0
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES(/*Some Values*/)
SET @totalRows =@totalRows + @@ROWCOUNT

INSERT INTO TABLE_B VALUES(/*Some Values*/)
SET @totalRows =@totalRows + @@ROWCOUNT

INSERT INTO TABLE_C VALUES(/*Some Values*/)
SET @totalRows =@totalRows + @@ROWCOUNT

Update Table Set Values A = A WHERE id = @id /* Some thing like that*/
SET @totalRows =@totalRows + @@ROWCOUNT

SELECT @totalRows As TotalRowsAffected
```

Comment: will it return all the affected rows, `like 3 Inserts + all affected rows of update`

Comment: No,@@rowcount only returns number of rows from previous statement.  declare local variables and immediately after DML statements copy the @@rowcount value to the local variable and add.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47635/discussion-between-mhasan-and-harshsharma)